# Find DIC values for another sample

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian, jags, dic

I trained a model using JAGS and I obtained parameter values. Can I calculate the DIC values for a subset of these data points. The code is

```
mod=jags.model(textConnection(mod_string), data=data_jags, n.chains=3)

dic= dic.samples(mod, n.iter=1000)
```

but I want to calculate the DIC for a subset of `data_jags`.

Comment: You could calculate it manually.  See my answer to this question for definitions of DIC, including the JAGS one:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331928/dic-waic-in-jags/476780#476780.  Since you have a subset of data, you would only sum over the observations in this subset. Otherwise, it's exactly the same.